# Narrow enum type to a single member

Tags: typescript

```
enum Unit {
    Kilometer,
    Meter,
}

interface Measurement {
    distanceUnit: Unit
    distance: number
}

interface MetersMeasurement {
    distanceUnit: Unit.Meter
}

function someCalculation(item: MetersMeasurement){
    return;
}

function main(){
    const item : Measurement = {
        distance: 100,
        distanceUnit: Unit.Meter
    }

    if(item.distanceUnit !== Unit.Meter) return;
    
    someCalculation(item)
                 // ^^^^ Types of property 'distanceUnit' are incompatible.     
                 //      Type 'Unit' is not assignable to type 'Unit.Meter'.
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqiCWAXKBvAUFTUDS8A2A9hMIsAE4A0GWAsieVQL5prwilkBmAhgMbBQ63AM5gywYu1TVMAE3jDE3EPzhIAXLASIZUeYuX9N4CACNyaZq3bke-QfTLCho8ZOTosehUpXA1iJoBAHR0HJYsnGAqiPAEIFDCRMAAwtx4vGB43LHxABRIEpph5M7AImISoIgAlJ5Y4ohiIADcEWhRMXEJENxseXW6vPGKUIXQxeWuVVIAvNJeXvq+RlAAjAAMG1SLWMuG-tpB2qGOulZe8JwFpBDB+34BUACEs-MhJWQ1UI3NbV66JLENIZLI5bo3CQ1SxAA)

1. If `MetersMeasurement` and `Measurement` had the same fields, we could use a type predicate to narrow it down. But my problem requires that `MetersMeasurement` will only have a subset of the fields of `Measurement`. Therefore a type predicate wouldn't work [[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAqiCWAXKBvAUFTUDS8A2A9hMIsAE4A0GWAsieVQL5prwilkBmAhgMbBQ63AM5gywYu1TVMAE3jDE3EPzhIAXLASIZUeYuX9N4CACNyaZq3bke-QfTLCho8ZOTosehUpXA1iJoBAHR0HLr6vkZQJuZkliycYCqI8AQgUMJEwADC3Hi8YHjcqekAFEgSmmHkzsAiYhKgiACUnljiiGIgANwJaEkpaRkKNU4uje4VpBDV9a5N7C1QmpXQCg4cdQ1uze2Ynd1Qa8GRhv7aUAC8N1pIoY6WUInJvKUZENxsZW26vOmKY4zFYOHaLZBXaReLxnPyaACMAAZEVRoVhYaptEFtA9wl4rF54JwygBCUaObYLKZrFrLQ5kXq6Ly6LLEPIFIolYbTCQtSxAA)].
2. We could also change the type of `distanceUnit` in the interface `MetersMeasurement` to `Unit`. And then move the `if` check for meters inside `someCalculation` function. But let's also say I don't want to do that. I don't want to give the function this responsibility.
3. We could create a new object of type `MetersMeasurement` based on the original object and then pass that to `someCalculation()` instead. But this feels like a workaround (and extra code) because we couldn't narrow down the type [[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqiCWAXKBvAUFTUDS8A2A9hMIsAE4A0GWAsieVQL5prwilkBmAhgMbBQ63AM5gywYu1TVMAE3jDE3EPzhIAXLASIZUeYuX9N4CACNyaZq3bke-QfTLCho8ZOTosehUpXA1iJoBAHR0HJYsnGAqiPAEIFDCRMAAwtx4vGB43LHxABRIEpph5M7AImISoIgAlJ5Y4ohiIADcEWhRMXEJENxseXW6vPGKUIXQxeWuVVIAvNJeXvq+RlAAjAAMG1SLWMuG-tpB2qGOulZe8JwFpBDB+34BUACEs-MhJWQ1UI3NbUMjZAgYAAdwAkrcoPN6rtgnDxjtdt4DI8jlokKcOFARFBhiBFOddLoksQ0hksjlunlgeDbjVLEA)].

Is there a way to properly narrow down the type without breaking the rules? (no `any` or casting)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to check whether or not the item is `MetersMeasurement` or `Measurement`

```
enum Unit {
    Kilometer,
    Meter,
}

interface Measurement {
    distanceUnit: Unit
    distance: number
}

interface MetersMeasurement {
    distanceUnit: Unit.Meter
}

function someCalculation(item: MetersMeasurement){
    return;
}

function isMeasurement(obj: Measurement): obj is Measurement {
  return (obj as Measurement).distance !== undefined;
}

function main(){
    const item = {
        distance: 100,
        distanceUnit: Unit.Meter
    }

    if(isMeasurement(item)) return;
    
    someCalculation(item)
}
```

Comment: We need to assert `obj is MetersMeasurement` instead of `obj is Measurement`. But changing it in your example breaks due to point #1 in my question.

Comment: The assertion is that obj has a distance attribute. So i'm checking whether `item` is a Measurement (therefore has a distance attribute)

Comment: The main problem I have is asserting that the obj has `distanceUnit: Unit.Meter`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
enum Unit {
    Kilometer,
    Meter,
}

type Distance = {
    distance: number;
}

type MetersMeasurement = {
    distanceUnit: Unit.Meter;
} & Distance

type KilometersMeasurement = {
    distanceUnit: Unit.Kilometer;
} & Distance

type Measurement = MetersMeasurement | KilometersMeasurement;


/*
 * return km
 */
function meterCalculation(item: MetersMeasurement) {
    return item.distance * .001;
}

function main(){
    const item : Measurement = {
        distance: 100,
        distanceUnit: Unit.Meter
    }

    if (item.distanceUnit == Unit.Meter) {
        meterCalculation(item);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqiCWAXKBvAUFTUDS8A2A9hMIsAE4A0GWAsieVQL5pqICeADsFACLwDOiAIYgAxtwC8qapgAmA4WOAAuKOAgAjcgG40zVp251SZfnSH8wZYMRDIp6LFHmCR4uElUfEAOmM69KAAyXgU3YBZ2Lhx8InpTc0trW3tpJxdFdwREL2yfXEJiE11GYNDXJUjDKESrG1BU-wTgCzqUqAAfGML4sxak%20rtdFgB6ACoMMahrRCsQKABrCEmRtAAzMDFEeAJ5ovIAYSE8UTA8IW3dgAokG1UmvtbkhoBKNKwZuahbiB8M8KgUx8AAZgQBGEosDZbHZ7ITwEBXF6OLCiXaCb6kaD3fptBpQBwyJzOMJKVRg0FUYlYf5Kby5JB%20eJE-ROeBrKA3LF-UlZJAEqTeJkmN4o6n7MhHE5nC6wrk2F66JzMJxEvRAA)

Comment: Thank you, but this would only work if I could afford to add `distance` to `MetersMeasurement` as you did here by adding `& Distance`.

If we could do this I would follow point #1 in my question.

Comment: if you don't want distance to be required then you can try: ```& Partial<Distance>```